# What is correct way to close persistent connection?

Tags: go, connection

My case is: long running server with connection to Redis. This server wait for SIGTERM signal for terminating. What is the right way to guarantee to release connection after terminating of my application?

I know about defer - is really great, but not for persistent connection, because I do not want to open connection to Redis for each operation.

Thanks!

Comment: All file descriptors are closed by the OS when your application exits. If you want to *try* to handle something before exiting, then you can use defer, but there's no way to guarantee any of your code runs when an application is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You would still use `defer` if you want to **ensure** some block of code executes before exit. The difference is in it's scope. The scope of your connection and defer statement should be the same. I have no idea what your app is but to provide a concrete example, you need to defer the connection close in the main of you command line app, not in the methods that read and write.

You said "because I do not want to open connection to Redis for each operation" but that only makes defer problematic if you defer the close in the scope of some method that does a single IO operation. If you instead do the defer in the scope above a single operation (where all operations occur) then it will do waht you want;

```
init connection
defer connectionClose

begin execution of code that does db IO
block here if above is async
program is exiting, my defer is called here
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the execution of deferred statements in not guaranteed. I just want to make it clear that you can defer the connection closing at the top level of application.

Comment: To complicate matters, defer will not be called on os.Exit. This question is also applicable when you want to flush buffered data out.

Comment: @ffk perhaps but I think the general idea of my answer is still correct. While `defer` may not cover __all__ shut down cases, the OP said that if he used it he would have to open a connection for each operation, which is not the case, that means his defer is being declared in the wrong scope. That's purely an inference on my part, but I think that's the issue he's facing. Not the issue of "how do I write/clean up with my computer literally turns off unexpectedly".

Comment: I agree, I primarily want to point out that calling os.Exit() will not run defer (which is a perfectly reasonable way to shut down apps, unlike pulling plugs :)